# Integer valued logarithmesque sequences $a_n$ with the property $a_{mn} = a_m + a_n$ for all $m, n \in \mathbb{N}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

I managed to prove that no monotonically increasing sequence of this kind exists (a sketch is included below).

As such, the only non-trivial one I could think of was $a_n = i$ such that $i$ is the largest $m$ with $p^m | n$ for prime $p$.

Are there any other general solutions that I have missed? I would appreciate some pointers if that is the case.

**Special case proof sketch**

Note that whatever be the sequence, $a_1$ must be zero (since $a_n = a_n + a_1$ for all $n$).

Now divide the possible sequences into strictly and weakly increasing cases.

*Strict case:* This requires $a_n \geq n-1$. By applying the definition, we get $a_{n^m} = ma_n \geq n^m - 1$. But the L.H.S. is linear and the R.H.S. is exponential, so this is impossible.

*Weak case:* Let $i$ be the smallest $n$ for which $a_n = a_{n+1}$. From the definition of the sequence this means $a_{2i} = a_{2i+2} = k$, and the fact that the sequence is non-decreasing means that $a_{2i+1}$ also has the same value. If $i$ is even, it can be shown that $a_{2i+3} = a_{2i+4} = k$ as well. This means (reversing the definition of the sequence) that $a_i = a_{i+2}$ which in turn means $a_\frac{i}{2} = a_\frac{i+2}{2}$, contradicting the minimality of $i$. A similar procedure works for odd $i$ (except I used $a_{2i-1}$). The main idea in both cases was that $a_i = a_{i+1} \Rightarrow a_{ni} = a_{n(i+1)}$, and all the values in between as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can generate all of these completely additive arithmetic functions as follows. Assign $a_p$ arbitrarily for prime $p$. For $n>1$, if $n=p_1^{k_1}\ldots p_m^{k_m}$ is the prime factorization of $n$, let $a_n=k_1a_{p_1}+k_2a_{p_2}+\ldots+k_ma_{p_m}$. For instance, if $a_p=1$ for all primes $p$, then in general $a_n=\Omega(n)$, the number of prime factors of $n$ with multiplicity. (You can find some information about $\Omega(n)$ [here](http://oeis.org/wiki/Omega(n),_number_of_prime_factors_of_n_(with_multiplicity)).)

Clearly all of these sequences have the desired property. However, it’s also clear that any sequence that has the property must satisfy the condition that $a_n=k_1a_{p_1}+k_2a_{p_2}+\ldots+k_ma_{p_m}$ when $n=p_1^{k_1}\ldots p_m^{k_m}$ is the prime factorization of $n$.

Comment: These are in fact all such sequences, by the fundamental theorem of arithmetic.

Comment: Ah. Somehow I missed this natural generalization.

Comment: @Whatsup Do you mean every $a_n$ is of this kind or that every such sequence is an $a_n$? The latter is fairly clear, but I am curious as to how the former follows from the Fundamental Theorem (if that is indeed what you meant).

Comment: I mean every sequence which satisfies your property can be constructed by the method described in this answer.

Comment: @WhatsUp: Thanks for pointing that out; I’ve added it to my answer.

Comment: @Whatsup I see that now. I can't believe I wasted all that time messing with monotony!